# How to get correct distance value using Mist pass

Tags: render-passes

I'm trying to use Mist data for getting values of [0,255] for Mist range of [Start, Start+Depth]. but I'v got into two problems:

1. Output values range is only [0,206] for [Start, Start+Depth]
2. Output values are non linear relative to [Start, Start+Depth] values

I'm Using Blender 3.1.2

Here is how I did up to now:

Building a scene of 5 elements, with heights of 0m, 1m, 2m, 3m and 4m.
[image]

Camera was placed directly above at height of 12m.

Mist start was set to 7.99 (in order to ensure the 4m height is in the Mist range)

Mist Depth was set to 4.02 (in order to ensure the 0m height is in the Mist range)

The Mist Falloff was set to be Linear.

[image]
[image]

Camera was set to Orthographic:

[image]

Only Mist data was enabled for output, that is the only data I need:

[image]

Now, checking the Mist data output yields the values: 0, 144, 178, 194 and 206, while I would expect to have 0,64,128,192 and 255:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve it, there is need to set Color Management parameters.

Display Device: sRGB, View Transform: Raw

or

Display Device: None, View Transform: Standard

[image]